# plotly express shows mid of the day marks that are not in the dataframe, how to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

how not to show mid of the 12pm on the chard. I want days only.
Here is the dataset from the chart https://easyupload.io/gxfiq1

```
df_combined = df_combined.sort_values(by='sold_date', ascending=True)
df_smt = df_combined.loc[df_combined['model'] == 'Adapt'].groupby('date').agg({'price': 'sum', 'sold_date': 'count'}).reset_index()
fig = px.line(df_smt, x='date', y='price', title='Adapt')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To accommodate this, a date interval must be set. The date interval is set in dtick, and the day unit is 1000 milliseconds x 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours. `fig.update_xaxes(type='date', dtick='86400000')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to update the "x-tick" labels. The plotly documentation has some information on how to do this (https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/)

Something like

```
fig.update_layout(
   xaxis_tickformat = '%b %d %Y',
)
```

should format the x-ticks as month (`%b`), day (`%d`), year (`%Y`).

You can see more information on formatting options here (https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/main/README.md)